# Can we spoof location in ipod using custom wifi hotspot?

Tags: ios, objective-c, geolocation, wifi, ipod-touch

Ipod uses wifi to get location. My question is can we create a custom wifi hotspot and do some hack to make ipod believe that its location is somewhere we want it to be? This is very critical as in my project I have to show items based on locations in US but I am living in India. So is there any method by which I can spoof location In US?

Comment: http://robots.thoughtbot.com/post/28649557009/faking-corelocation-inconceivable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a custom location to be simulated in your Project scheme. This simulation will be then "faked" both for your Simulator and when you run straight from Xcode on your device.

Project -> Edit scheme -> enable location, and choose from the pre-defined list or add your own custom .gpx file

Comment: Also there is a shortcut for that. In the lower pane of xcode when we run the app a location icon will be shown. We can click on it and add gpx files.

Answer (score 0):

Geolocation without GPS is done in two ways:

1. Apple has it's own database of WiFi networks and their locations. If you set up a new WiFi hotspot and connect to it, Apple most likely won't be able to take a location from it alone, as they won't know about it yet.
2. Your external IP address can be traced to the country and sometimes city that you live in. This can be spoofed using a proxy server.

Are you trying to spoof your location to a web server or using the geo-location API? The correct approach will depend on what you are trying to spoof.

Comment: @0x7fffffff - yes, most likely: http://www.zdnet.com/apple-iphone-data-used-to-build-wi-fi-hotspot-database-3040092624/ It's not just Apple that do this. Google's Street View cars log the location of SSIDs and possibly router MAC addresses as they drive around.